# If the square of an integer number $x$ is even, then $x$ has to be even.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

My math textbook had the following statement but did not mention how it got there, so I tried to find a proof. Can someone please verify if it is correct.

**Statement:**
If the square of an integer number $x$ is even, then $x$ has to be even.

**Proof:**

We know that $x^2$ is even, so we can write it in the form of an even number

$$x^2 = 2n$$

$$x = \sqrt2 \sqrt n$$

We know that $x$ is an integer and hence a rational number

$$x=(\sqrt2 \sqrt n) \times\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2}$$

$$x=2(\sqrt\frac{n}{2})$$

Since $n$ is a natural number and $\sqrt(\frac{n}{2})$ is rational (because 2 and x are rational and the quotient of two rational numbers is rational). $n$ can only assume those values which allow $\sqrt(\frac{n}{2})$ to come out rational. In other words, $\frac{n}{2}$ has to be a perfect square.

Now $x=2p$ where $p$ is an integer and hence $x$ is even.

Comment: odd x odd = odd, so it must be even x even = even.

Comment: "since $x$ is an integer $\sqrt{\frac n2}$ also has to be an integer" Why then?

Comment: @drhab Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed that last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a [prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) (or a prime) is defined as a natural number greater than $1$ that cannot be formed by multiplying two smaller natural numbers then with [unique prime decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) it can be shown that for integers $a,b$ and prime $p$:$$p\mid ab\iff p\mid a\text{ or }p\mid b$$

Applying that on $p=2$ and $a=b=x\in\mathbb Z$ we find:$$2\mid x^2\iff 2\mid x$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your proof looks alright to me. However, more conventionally, you could use contradiction proofs for these types of questions.

**Theorem:** $x^2$ is even $\implies$ $x$ is even

**Proof:** Assume for a contradiction that $x^2$ is even and $x$ is odd. Then

\begin{align}
x & = 2k+1 \\
x^2& = (2k+1)^2 \\
& = 4k^2 + 4k+1 \\
& = 2(2k^2+2k)+1 \\
\end{align}

Which is in the form $2n+1$, so $x^2$ is odd. However, we assumed $x^2$ is even. Hence a contradiction is found and $x$ cannot be odd.

$\therefore x^2$ is even $\implies$ $x$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

I would prove the contrapositive: if $x$ is odd, then so is $x^2$.

In your proof, you write:

> $$x = 2\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$$
>   Since $x$ is an integer, $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$ also has to be an integer.

This is only true if $x$ is even, the fact that you're trying to prove.

It's also worth pointing out that this proposition is typically used in the standard proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. There's nothing necessarily wrong with using irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ to prove it, so long as you have another proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational to hand.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have made a change to the last part and yes, if I had to, I would probably use that proof by contradiction to show that root 2 is irrational since I haven't let studied the lower bound concepts yet.